# Magento page not loading

Tags: php, xml, magento, config

I'm trying to follow this tutorial: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/magefordev/mage-for-dev-5.html

I am using Magento 1.9.x (not 2)

I'm stuck at creating a weblog module, the module is enabled but the path isn't working in my browser.

IndexController.php in code/local/Magentotutorial/Weblog/controllers/IndexController.php

```
<?php
class Magentotutorial_Weblog_IndexController extends 
    Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {
        public function testModelAction() {
            echo 'Setup!';
        }
    }
```

Magentotutorial_Weblog.xml in app/etc/modules/Magentotutorial_Weblog.xml

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Magentotutorial_Weblog>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Magentotutorial_Weblog>
</modules>
```

config.xml in app/code/local/Magentotutorial/Weblog/etc/config.xml

```
<frontend>
<routers>
    <weblog>
        <use>standard</use>
        <args>
            <module>Magentotutorial_Weblog</module>
            <frontName>weblog</frontName>
        </args>
    </weblog>
</routers>
</frontend>
```

I try to load the page http://localhost/MagentoTut/weblog/index/testModel, but it comes up with 404 Not Found. Am I missing something that I need to create a module? It says the module is enabled in my admin panel so maybe the routing is not right?

Thanks so much.

Comment: I don't see your view. Where is your template?

Comment: @NMoeini I think OP is only trying to display `echo 'Setup!';` from controller. So view is not there

Comment: Yeah not trying to use a template yet. Thanks for clarifying B. Desai.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the issue. It was with my config.xml file, I've modified it to look like this:

```
<config>    
<modules>
    <Magentotutorial_Weblog>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Magentotutorial_Weblog>
</modules>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <weblog>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Magentotutorial_Weblog</module>
                <frontName>weblog</frontName>
            </args>
        </weblog>
    </routers>  
</frontend>
</config>
```

Thanks :)